# Python Elasticsearch, RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception') happens intermittently. Why?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm running basic filters on an elasticsearch (v. 1.7) cluster using Python Elasticsearch. Surprisingly, I can run the exact same code repeatedly and have a successful query about 1/2 the time, and receive a TransportError 400 about 1/2 the time. I'd like to know if the cause of this is my syntax, or something out of my control.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch    
host_list = [HOST3, HOST4]
client = Elasticsearch(hosts = host_list, timeout = 120)
q = {"from" : 0, 
            "size" : 0,
            "query": {
              "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {"term": {
                        "field1": ["value1"]
                      }}, 
                      {"term": {
                        "field2": ["value2"]
                      }}
                    ],
                  "must": [
                    {"range": {
                      "times": {
                        "gte": "2015-04-21T00:00:00Z",
                        "lte": "2015-04-22T00:00:00Z"
                      }
                    }}
                  ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }}
res = client.search(index = "index_name", doc_type = ("doc_type_name"), body = q)
```

returns

```
RequestError               Traceback (most recent call last)
--> 265         res = client.search(...)
(omitting long traceback through ES module code) 
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception')
```

But the other half of the time I get a valid result?! Any ideas?

Comment: what does your ES logs say?

Comment: I don't know how to see the ES log. I'm accessing a remote cluster, so I don't have the ES `/log` directory at my disposal--- or do i?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the body of the exception.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your hosts from `host_list` is down or in a bad shape? That could explain the 1/2 ratio. Or maybe one or more shards of your index are in bad shape as well.

Comment: can you ssh into remote server and check logs? also as @Val suggested, try running `curl -XGET 'http://remote_host:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'` and make sure everything is fine

Comment: Can't ssh. `_cluster/health` shows status is yellow. This code is producing repeatedly producing no errors now. I just ran ~10 similar but different queries about 5 times each with no errors. Evidence is a connection error?

Comment: Can you restrain `host_list` to just `HOST3` and retry and then to just `HOST4` and retry? What does it give you?

Comment: HA! You got it @Val. One host is 10/10.The other is 0/10, and I ran another experiment with both in the list and went 5/10 exactly (probably a fluke that it hit exactly). I'm convinced - we've got a dead ship. Maybe you should make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably one of your hosts that is dead. You should try to restrain `host_list` to `HOST3` and retry and then restrain `host_list` to only `HOST4` and retry. You'll immediately see if one of your hosts is down or not.

Comment: I am having same issue with hosts: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. How can it be dead? app is running, I am trying to run methods manually to update a few records in a db. It was working fine until yesterday.. cannot find the reason for `raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception')`

Comment: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'` returns healthy, but python elasticsearch cannot establish connection: `{
...
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 5,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 5,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}`

Comment: @user305883 You should create another question with detailed explanation, comments are not ideal for that.